# Copy char input into array of strings

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays, char

I'm currently refreshing my C skills and having trouble with the following code:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    @autoreleasepool {

        int numberOfTestCases;

        scanf("%d", &numberOfTestCases);

        char *a[numberOfTestCases];

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTestCases; i++) {

            char input[100];
            scanf("%s", input);
            a[i] = input;
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < numberOfTestCases; k++) {
            printf("%s\n", a[k]);
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

First I want to enter the user a number to determine how many strings she/he wants to enter.

Second I want to let the user enter the number of strings and store them in an array of strings.

Last I want to loop over that array and print out all the values. So my test input is e.g. something like:

5

My

name

is

John

Doe

**with an expected result of**

My

name

is

John

Doe

**Instead the result is:**

Doe

Doe

Doe

Doe

Doe

I can't figure out how to insert the input in the array.. very thankful for a hint in the right direction.

Comment: That is not a C program, neither is it C++. Possibly Objective-C.

Comment: Your title mentions `NSStringWithFormat`, which is Objective-C, but your code or question body don't even seem relevant to the title.

Comment: Oh, and `a[i] = input;` will make each array element point to the same `char input[100];` which also goes out of scope outside the `for` loop.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong title. That was an old browser cache error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***If*** that was a C program, you would have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because you have an array of pointers, and each pointer you make point to a variable inside a nested scope, which means that variable will be out of scope outside of the loop, and the pointers (who are all pointing to the same memory) will be stray leading to said undefined behavior.

Comment: I would guess that it would be undefined behavior in Objective-C as well.